# save created pdf to remote server using php

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I need to created pdf in my project  so I am using pdfmake js plugin it is working fine but I want to put that file to server, I tried to do this using file_put_content but this is not working,my question is how to put pdf file to server once it is generated by plugin.

```
<button class="btn btn-success">Generate pdf</button>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.22/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>


    <script>
     $("body").on("click", ".save_changes", function () {

        var ts = String(new Date().getTime()), i = 0, out = '';
        for (i = 0; i < ts.length; i += 2) {
            out += Number(ts.substr(i, 2)).toString(36);
        }
        var newdate = ('d' + out);
        html2canvas($('#page-wrap')[0], {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                            image: data,
                            width: 500
                        }]
                };
         
                   pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(newdate + ".pdf");
                   
                   
                var file_created = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
                <?php
$file_location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "folder_name/pdfReports/";
file_put_contents($file_location, $pdf);
?>
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: What exactly does the PHP variable `$pdf` contain?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson by mistake I kept,  we can't assign  js variable value to php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) - PHP is _server side_ and Javascript is _client side_. They can't "share" variables. They are executed in completely different environment. You can send data (like the file contents of the PDF) from Javascript to PHP, using Ajax or similar.

Comment: Instead of downloading i want to save to server,any idea?

Comment: yes, client side language is different from server side,so no chance to save.

Comment: You can send the file to your server using Ajax. Search for "upload using ajax" and you should get a bunch of different examples.